# Defining case for time condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show JobTime in the the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'Urgent' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=240 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - Urgent'
    WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'High' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=720 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - High'
    WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'Medium' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=1440 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - Medium'
    WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'Low' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=2880 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - Low'
END  AS [Problem_Type_Name]
```

JobTime calculation is as follows:

```
CASE WHEN (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end) <0THEN 0 ELSE (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end)  END AS JobTime
```

Is there any possible or easy way to use the JobTime in select?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  As for the answer to your question, there are zillions of ways to use `JobTime` in a `SELECT`.

Comment: Since an answer has been accepted without the question being edited to show data to make it more understandable, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your case statement into an outer apply, which will allow you to reference the field in your select statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'Urgent' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=240 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - Urgent'
     WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'High' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=720 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - High'
     WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'Medium' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=1440 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - Medium'
     WHEN [PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] = 'Low' AND ISNULL(JobTime,0) <=2880 THEN 'NOC Service Request Resolution - Low'
END  AS [Problem_Type_Name], 
oa.JobTime

FROM dbo.TableName (NOLOCK) t
OUTER APPLY ( 
                  SELECT CASE WHEN (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end) <0THEN 0 ELSE (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end)  END AS JobTime
            ) oa
```